# Best way of storing hierarchical data in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-science

I'm trying to use pandas for storing hierarchical data which consists of some long arrays, containing position data(latitude, longitude and etc.) and some further details about the name of the test, the date of it and some other meta information. Its structure looks like following:

```
 Dataframe
    |---- Position|---- Latitude (float array,length=N)
    |             |---- Longitude(float array,length=N)
    |             |---- Timestamp(float array,length=N)
    |
    |---- Test Name(string)
    |---- Test Date(string)
    |---- Measurement Device(string)
    |---- etc.
```

My problem is that the elements of my metadata (including test name and etc.) have a different length compared with the other array shaped data and I need to find a way to store them together in a pandas data structure (like pandas Dataframe).

I've searched on the internet for solutions and I found the hierarchical indexing feature in pandas as a potential solution. But when I tried to save such a Dataframe as .json file, the output JSON file contained syntax errors and couldn't be opened.

My question is, does anyone know what is the effective way of storing hierarchical data with lengths in pandas?

Comment: you'll need to flatten the json before doing your transformation, to that end you've provided no data for anyone to help you. Your question is highly subjective and dependent on your source data.

Comment: I'm taking a guess here, but if you want to store geographic information along with data for each said location, look at [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/)

Comment: You could use separate tables. One would be uniquely keyed by DataFrame, (one row per DataFrame) with the attributes of that DataFrame. The other would be uniquely keyed by (DataFrame, Position). You can merge/map back the other information when necessary.

Comment: @ALollz If I want to save the Dataframes as a file, should I have two separate files for each one?

Comment: @piRSquared I will definitely take a look at it. Can I save it as a JSON or hf5 file too?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure.  It just occurred to me that it may be useful to you.